# Trying to use a popup window from a bottom sheet (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to open a Popup Window from a BottomSheet in my app and I want it to open above the bottom sheet.

This is my code.

```
private void setUpPriorityPopUpWindow()
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) requireContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_priority_popup_window,null);

    tasksPriorityPopUp = new PopupWindow(v, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
}
```

In the OnCreateView of my BottomSheetFragment:

```
    ImageButton priority = v.findViewById(R.id.priority);
    setUpPriorityPopUpWindow();
    priority.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tasksPriorityPopUp.showAsDropDown(v);
        }
    });
```

Help of any sort would be deeply appreciated.

EDIT: It is currently opening behind the BottomSheet

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Dialog` or a `DialogFragment` instead of inflating the view.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle("Delete entry")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")

    // Specifying a listener allows you to take an action before dismissing the dialog.
    // The dialog is automatically dismissed when a dialog button is clicked.
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // Continue with delete operation
        }
     })

    // A null listener allows the button to dismiss the dialog and take no further action.
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .show();
```

```
class PurchaseConfirmationDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog =
            AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.order_confirmation))
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok)) { _,_ -> }
                .create()

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "PurchaseConfirmationDialog"
    }
}
```